# What's the advantages of writing standard calculus into lie differentiation?

Tags: calculus, lie-derivative

Say $\dot{x} = f(x)$, $x\in\mathcal{M}$, $\phi: \mathcal{M} \mapsto \mathcal{M}$.

Then $\dot{\phi} = f \cdot \nabla_x \phi $.

However, one can define a lie differentiation and write

$f \cdot \nabla_x \phi = \mathcal{L}_f \phi$.

## QUESTION:

What is the point of doing this? Is there any nice things we could get from writing things in lie differentiation while hard to get in standard calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia article on [Lie Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) actually nicely answers this question:
"A 'naïve' attempt to define the derivative of a tensor field with respect to a vector field would be to take the components of the tensor field and take the directional derivative with respect to the vector field of each component. However, this definition is undesirable because it is not invariant under changes of coordinate system"

It is that last sentence that is of vital importance, as much of the power of the machinery of differential geometry is in its independence from choice of coordinates (hence you can choose convenient ones for the problem at hand).

Comment: but can this notation really gives me something nice, e.g., a corollary, a theorem, an identity that I couldn't get with just write a dot with the divergence?

Comment: The difference can be seen if you derive the resulting Change of Variables formula for both of the definitions. The naive definition gives a less elegant and harder to utilize result (because it is not invariant under a change of coordinates).

Comment: @JustinBenfield: Hi! I'm a bit confused with the last line: "this definition is undesirable because it is not invariant under changes of coordinate system". What does being invariant under coord system changes mean here? I mean, if we have (say) $(1,1)$-tensor $T^i_j$, then its components will depend on the chart. Similarly if we have a vector field $V^i$ and consider $S^i_j=\partial_jV^i$, the components $S^i_j$ will also be chart dependent. So what's the difference between the two cases and in what sense is $T$ coordinate independent but $S$ isn't?

Comment: @ShirishKulhari If you have a look at the change of coordinates for a triple integral from rectangular to spherical coordinates, you will notice that not only do you have to re-express the integrand, $f(x,y,z)$ in the new coordinates, but the differential, $d x d y d z$ is replaced by $\rho^2\sin \theta d r d \theta d \phi$

Comment: @JustinBenfield : Thanks! Another explanation that I was considering was that is the components of some object don't transform like that of a tensor, then they can't contract with basis elements in just the right way. This means that that object won't remain unchanged under a change of coordinates