# Defining the derivative of a vector field component

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

I'm reading 'Core Principles of Special and General Relativity' by Luscombe, specifically the introductory section on problems with defining usual notion of differentiation for tensor fields. I'll quote the relevant part:

> The second way (to see whether the partial derivative of a tensor is a tensor) is to look at the definition of derivative, $$\frac{\partial T^i}{\partial x^j}=\lim_{dx^j\to 0}\frac{T^i(x+dx^j)-T^i(x)}{dx^j}$$ The numerator is not in general a vector! We're comparing (subtracting) vectors from different points, yet the transformation properties of tensors are defined *at a point*.

Since the equation above is a notational mess, here's my attempt to interpret it:
$$\bigg(\frac{\partial T^i}{\partial x^j}\bigg)_p=\partial_j(T^i\circ x^{-1})(x(p))=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(T^i\circ x^{-1})(x(p)+[0,\ldots,h,\ldots,0])-(T^i\circ x^{-1})(x(p))}{h}$$ where $[0,\ldots,h,\ldots,0]\in\mathbb{R}^n$ has $h$ as its $j$-th coordinate.

Is my above interpretation correct? If so, what's the issue with defining the derivative of a vector field component in this way?

Comment: The issue is that the tensor $T$ is the section of some vector bundle, and so $T(x)$ and $T(x + dx_j)$ are elements of different fibers of the bundle, so they cannot be subtracted. So the numerator of that limit expression actually does not make sense. This what the "Lie derivative" is for. It gets around this issue.

Comment: @Nick: My confusion is that if you look at the last expression of the last equation, the numerator does make sense because $(T^i\circ x^{-1})$ is a chart-dependent $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ map. In other words, if I define $S^i_j=\partial_jT^i$, then $S^i_j$ represents the components the object $S$ - where the components are chart-dependent. But then I can say the same for any $(1,1)$-tensor field - that also has chart-dependent components so that's nothing new. And that's why I think I'm missing something else.

Comment: Maybe the answer to the following question helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690285/whats-the-advantages-of-writing-standard-calculus-into-lie-differentiation/3690291#3690291.  Your expression may be valid, but it's coordinate dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've defined is exactly how one would normally define the partial derivative of a tensor component $\partial_j T^i$, which, *given a coordinate system*, is perfectly well defined (locally). The problem is that we cannot easily interpret $\partial_j T^i$ as the components of a coordinate independent object.

There's a bit of a pedagogical divide in how this subject is approached in math and in physics. In physics, it's common to define everything in coordinates and define (coordnate independent) tensors as collections of component functions which transform appropriately under change of coordinates. In this view, $\partial_j T^i$ is not a tensor because it does not transform properly. When Luscombe writes that an obeject is "not a vector" they mean that if cannot be interpreted as the components of a tangent vector defined independently of coordinates.

In mathematics, it's more common to define things in a coordinate independent way first, and only afterword write out the coordinate representation.

As an example, take the differential of a smooth function $f\in C^\infty M$. It can be defined as a covector field whose action on tangent vectors is given by $df(v):=v(f)$, which is manifestly coordinate independent. In coordinates, we would have
$$
df=\partial_i f\ dx^i
$$
The left side can only be defined locally, and only with respect to a chosen coordinate system, but because it behaves like a covector under change of coordinates, we could *define* $df:=\partial_i f\ dx^i$ and still interpret it as a coordinate independent covector.

Problems arise when we try to write a coodrinate independent derivative of tensor fields, though. The coordinate free equivalent of the (nonsense) equation given above would be something like
$$
\partial_v T(p):=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{T(\gamma(h))-T(p)}{h},\ \ \ \ \ \text{$\gamma$ is a path satisfying $\gamma(0)=p$, $\dot{\gamma}(0)=v$}
$$
This definition is still nonsense, since it doesn't make sense subtract tensors above different points, and because we want to define things in a coordinate independent way, there's no way to proceed.

Comment: I see. So the mathematicians' motivation for covariant diff is that we can't subtract tensors at different points, and physicists' motivation for the same is that they want the derivative components to transform like tensor components. One thing though: in what sense is a usual $(1,1)$-tensor $T^i_j$ "coordinate independent" and the derivative component $\partial_jT^i$ as I wrote in the question **not** coordinate independent? I mean, even $T^i_j$ components are chart dependent, aren't they?

Comment: I mean, what comes to my mind is that the chart dependent components $T^i_j$ can be "contracted" with the local chart dependent tensor basis elements, and due to their counteracting transformation laws, it just so happens that the contracted version doesn't change no matter the chart. But for the partial derivative components $\partial_jT^i$, there's no way for me to contract them appropriately to form a chart-independent object. Is that it?

Comment: The transformation law for $(1,1)$ tensors between a coordinate system $x^i$ and $y^\alpha$ is given by $$T^\alpha_\beta=\frac{\partial y^\alpha}{\partial x^a}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial y^\beta}T^a_b$$Applying this transformation to $\partial_a T^b$ does not give $\partial_\alpha T^\beta$, so the construction does not give a coordinate independent $(1,1)$ tensor.

Comment: Also, the mathematician's and physicist's motivation are ultimately the same, though described in very different ways. Both wish to define a coordinate independent operator $\nabla$ which "behaves like" the partial derivative in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Ultimately such an operator exists, and can be uniquely chosen given a metric, but it will differ from the coordinate derivatives $\partial_i$ in a nontrivial way.